# Accessing response (output) headers in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Trying to output an image from a protected area using ZF2. In my action function I output the image data with a call to:

`readfile($path);`

In the browser this output is recognized as text and displayed starting with jpeg markers 'ÿØÿà...bla bla bla'. I'm assuming this is because Zend returned a 'text' content type in the HTTP header.

So then I tried to change the content type header with php command

`header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Zend/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/ImagesController.php:84)
```

I looked extensively and found lots of documentation like [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.headers.html) that seems to say I can do something like:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
```

When I do that I get the message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response::setHeader() in /Zend/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/ImagesController.php on line 39
```

Looking through the response object structure I don't see any link between Zend\Http\Headers and the Zend\Http\Response object or the Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response object so it is not surprising that php can't find the call to setHeader().

My question is how do I change the output header to make the borwser expect image data?

Here is my code in response to the first answer. It doesn't use a view since it is just outputting binary data:

```
    class ImagesController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function getfileAction() {
        $path = '/data/images/theImage.jpg';
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        //$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type:', 'image/jpeg');
        readfile($path);
        exit; }}
```

In response to Saeven's reply here is my exact implementation of your solution:

```
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Http\Headers as Headers;

class ImagesController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function getfileAction() {
        $table = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('table');
        $fileName = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('filename');
        $path = '/datasm/apps/php/data/'.$table.'/'.$fileName;
        $imageData = file_get_contents($path);
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setContent($imageData);
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Here is a screen cap of my project showing that I don't have a corresponding view file for the getfileAction() 
[image: no view file for getFileAction]

Here is a screen cap of how I am testing using the browser and what is coming back from zend.

[image: output at the browser]

regarding the version of zend I am using 2.2.5.

Comment: on the side note , in the controller u can use $this->params('table') or $this->params()->fromRoute('table')

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:**

```
$response
    ->getHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageContent));
```

**Original Answer :**

this is what i used for a xml file :

```
$response = new \Zend\Http\Response();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
$response->setContent($xml);
return $response;
```

Comment: Thanks. This DOES change the header returned which solves my original issue but is still not changing my data to display as an image. I also added a header for content-length since it was setting that value to 1. When I set the length using the filesize($path) it returned all the image data but as a string. In other words it wasn't returning binary data but my binary data converted to string data. So now it seems I am having trouble with the part where I read the image with $imageData = file_get_contents($path) and set it with $response->setContent($imageData).

Comment: try this :     $response
        ->getHeaders()
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageContent));

Answer (score 1):

Use the response, definitely.  Can the call to header(), and use:

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setContent($imagedata);
$response
    ->getHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png');
return $response;
```

Also, return the response to skip RENDER and FINISH dispatch events.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't change the header which I verified is still Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Did you return the response rather than rely on the default ViewModel?  I've used this strategy like bread and butter.  What version of ZF2 are you using?

Comment: >bread and butter. Yes should be easy agreed. I added a lot of detail above that should answer you questions. Zend Framework version is 2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `ImageModel`(similiar to ViewModel) and `ImageStrategy`.

For example, from your controller,

```
$image =  new ImageModel();
$image->setFileName('my_file_name.png');
return $image;
```

You should create `ImageStrategy`(Custom View Strategy) and `ImageModel`(just extend ViewModel) by yourself.

I have sent a pull request to `WebinoPhpThumb` with the addition of `ImageStrategy` and `ImageModel`. You can view [here](https://github.com/webino/WebinoImageThumb/pull/5)

**Update**

I have created a module, [HtImgModule](https://github.com/hrevert/HtImgModule) which might help you. Read the docs [here](https://github.com/hrevert/HtImgModule/blob/0.3.0/docs/Images%20From%20Controller.md).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further about how to create the ImageStrategy and ImageModel.

Comment: I have sent a pull request to `WebinoPhpThumb` with the addition of `ImageStrategy` and `ImageModel`. You can view here https://github.com/webino/WebinoImageThumb/pull/5

Comment: [HtIimgModule](https://github.com/hrevert/HtImgModule) might help you.

https://github.com/hrevert/HtImgModule/blob/master/docs/Images%20From%20Controller.md

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the line:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
```

is before any output. So make sure it is before the `readfile($path);` and make sure that you don't have any white space or invisible characters before your opening `<?php` tags.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added my controller code above to show you exactly what's going on. It still returns the Call to Undefined method error.

Comment: @smDeveloper It definitely has to do with some output being sent before you call `header('Content-type: image/png');`. I don't thing Zend would send any output before your action gets called, so it must be some whitespace before your `<?php` at the beginning of a file. It could be in the `ImagesController` file or in your front controller. It's less likely that it's somewhere else.

Comment: it's not a good idea to change header like that when using a framework like zend where it provides the tolls to do that the right way